# Dynamodb Query in nodejs to filter a pagination result using query operation before the limit is taken

Tags: filter, pagination, amazon-dynamodb

I want DynamoDB query in NodeJs for pagination with filter expression.
I have done with Scan => Limit => Filter but,
I want to Scan => Filter => Limit

Answer (score 0):

For anything other than one time tools that modify the database structure, or something similar you should not be using scan in dynamodb.

What you want to use is Query and have your PK and SK be your filter, with the SK also being your sort.

Without knowing more details it would be hard to give an example.

| PK | SK |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| B | 4 |

they you would query for A and you would get 1 and 2 back,

Query for B and you would get 3 and 4 back (along with any data)

Pagination and limit is built into the Dynamodb api
you use Limit and ExclusiveStartKey